# ajax accordion with jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       var cont = $("#<%=txtCount.ClientID %>").val();
       alert(cont)
       for (var i = 0; i < cont; i++) {
           if (i % 2 != 0) {
               $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Accordion1_Pane_" + i + "_header").addClass("accordion-header2");
           }
       }
   });
```

Hello I have a problem I try to create every other row a different color with the accordion, I can but when I open the contents of the accordion back in addition to the previous point I have PagedDataSourc and when I move a page so it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead:

```
 $('.accordion-header').removeClass('accordion-header2').filter(':odd').addClass('accordion-header2');
```

This solution requires that all accordion elements in question have the 'accordion-header' class